# 3D-plotting nested dictionaries made up of different length arrays

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot, nested

I have a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
dictionary = {time: {pixels: {intensity}}}

len(time) = 65

len(pixels) = 6/time

len(intensity) = 6/pixel
```

Just to be clear, for 1 time value --> [1,2,3,4,5,6] pixel values --> sub values for each of the pixel values are 6 intensity values.

Example:

```
dictionary = {time1 : {1: array([i11,i12,i13,i14,i15,i16]), 2: array([i21,i22,i23,i24,i25,i26]), 3: array([i31,i32,i33,i34,i35,i36]), 4: array([i41,i42,i43,i44,i45]), 5: array([i51,i52,i53,i54,i55,i56]), 6: array([i61,i62,i63,i64,i65,i66])}}
```

My question is,
how do I plot these values (3D plot) with time in the z axis and intensity values and pixel values (since both are length 6) on y and x values respectively?

The following is what I have tried so far and have been unsuccessful:

```
   x = []
   y = []
   z = []
   for i in dictionary:
      z1 = i
      z.append(z1)
      x1 = dictionary[i].keys()
      x.append(x1)
      y1 = dictionary[i].values()
      y.append(y1)

   from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
   fig = plt.figure()
   ax = Axes3D(fig)
   ax.plot(x, y, zs = 0, zdir='z', label='zs=0,zdir=z')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `y` is a list of lists. It is easy to see the mistake, if you use listed `for` loops.

**Corrected code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x, y, z = [], [], []

for tim, pixels in dictionary.items():
    for pixel, intensities in pixels.items():
        for intensity in intensities:
            x.append(intensity)
            y.append(pixel)
            z.append(tim)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot(x, y, z, zdir='z')
ax.show()
```

**Example use:**

Using the simple dataset:

```
{1: {1: array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]), 2: array([21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]),
  3: array([31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]), 4: array([41, 42, 43, 44, 45]),
  5: array([51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56]), 6: array([61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66])},
 2: {1: array([71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76]), 2: array([21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]),
  3: array([31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]), 4: array([41, 42, 43, 44, 45]),
  5: array([51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56]), 6: array([61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66])}}
```

That would result in:
[image]

Comment: thanks but I get the following error:ERROR: AttributeError: 'Axes3D' object has no attribute 'show' [unknown]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Axes3D' object has no attribute 'show'

Comment: Nevermind, I typed matplotlib.pyplot.show() instead of ax.show() and it works out! Thanks so much!!!